# How to put parts of one table into another table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need help with two tables in a MySQL DB.
Both tables deal with ZipCodes in the USA.
The problem I have found is, not all zipcodes are contained in each table.
One table has zipcodes that the other does not and vice versa.

So...I can solve this either of two ways...1) Find someone who has a DB of all the USA zipcodes and get a copy from them.  Or 2) find someone who can help me write a script to copy data from one table and insert it into the other table.  So that I end up with one table with all the zipcodes in it.  What I envision is searching one table for zipcodes that are NOT found in the other table, then inserting that missing zipcode into the other table.

Keep in mind that there is more than just a field for zipcode.  We also have county, state, longitude, latitude, city....etc.

My final goal is to have one table with all the USA zipcodes along with the correct longitude and latitude for each zipcode.

Anybody out there have either of these solutions?

Comment: 3) find a complete copy instead of trying to finagle your two obviously incomplete copies and hoping their merger produces a complete set.

Comment: `INSERT INTO t1 SELECT col1,col2...FROM t2 WHERE t1.col1<>t2.col1 AND...`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (SELECT zipcode FROM table2)
```

You'll have to add the extra fields yourself since you didn't post them I don't know what they are.

`INSERT IGNORE` just skips any records that are duplicates.

(You do have a `unique` index on the zipcode column right?)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, here are two of them

Way 1:

```
    INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2 ... zip_column) 
SELECT column1, column2 ... zip_column FROM table2 
WHERE table2.zip_column NOT IN (SELECT zip_column FROM table 1)
```

Way 2 (The better one):

Create an unique index over zip code column in table1 and:

```
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (column1, column2 ... zip_column) 
SELECT column1, column2 ... zip_column FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (county, state, longitude, latitude, city .... add more here) 
  SELECT table2.area,table2.zipcode FROM table2 
  LEFT JOIN table1 ON 
         (
          table2.county=table1.county AND 
          table2.state=table1.state AND
          table2.longitude=table1.longitude AND
          table2.latitude=table1.latitude AND
          .... add more here
         ) 
  WHERE 
      table1.county IS NULL OR 
      table1.state IS NULL OR
      table1.longitude IS NULL OR
      table1.latitude IS NULL OR
      .... add more here
```